# How do I add a controller to my custom extension? TYPO3 9.5

Tags: controller, typo3

I'm fairly new to typo3..I've created my own content element based from this page:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/7.6/AddingYourOwnContentElements/Index.html

I've got the field values displayed on the front-end, i'm now trying to pass the field values to a fluid form and want to know how I instantiate a controller so I can retrieve the values?

anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Have you added your current work to a page? If yes, can u search the current record in the database and tell us what you find in the column `CType`?

Comment: Please post the code that you got so far, `content element` || `plugin`, both are not so complicated, we just need to know what you got and want.

Comment: Please write a little bit about what your content element should do. You may want to create a plugin using the Extbase framework with Controller actions. This is a different approach from what is described in the above mentioned documentation. You may want to look at https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/4-FirstExtension/Index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content elements do not use a Controller. Extensions on the other hand use a controller.

What you have to do, is to get the data via database queries and you can achieve that via TypoScript and to be more specific, `dataProcessing`. You can get an idea how here:

https://learn-typo3.com/blog/news-detail/how-to-create-custom-content-elements-on-typo3

or here

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html#dataprocessing

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

If I explain in brief, custom fluid elements in the TYPO3 and TYPO3 extension both are different things.

**What you have done...**

You have created the custom fluid element which is using existing **tt_content** fields (or custom added fields). With this, you can use the element directly as part of fluid_styled_content. The link you have provided is referring to the same!

**What you're looking for...**

You need a controller that means you need a custom extension. However, I am not sure what you want to archive. You can find a reference for how to create an extension for TYPO3.

- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/4-FirstExtension/Index.html
- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-extbasefluid/master/en-us/Extbase/FirstExtbaseExtension.html

Hope this helps you!